# How to Join with a column having Comma Separated Values in Linq

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, linq, linq-to-sql

I have one master table Category.

```
ID | Name
----------
1  | Category1
2  | Category2
3  | Category3
4  | Category4
```

And Another Table Details have field like

```
ID | CategoryId | Detail
--------------------
1  | 1,2,3      | Test1
2  | 3,4        | Test2
```

Here the Category Id stored as comma separated values.
Now i want the result as

```
ID | CategoryName
----------------
1  | Category1,Category2,Category3
2  | Category3,Category4
```

AnyOne Have idea ..??

Comment: I'd strongly suggest normalizing your data.

Comment: But i can't do it , its the requirement of my project.

Comment: Review them with your managers or tech leads. This is going to cause even more issues in the future. As a workaround you can create a split string function to split your string into rows, join them with categories and then concatenate them again. But that's done in SQL Server. This is only a workaround to your problem. Not a solution.

Comment: ok Thanks @EvaldasBuinauskas

Comment: The design should not be like this. I would recommend, the data should be in normalized from. Because it would create many issues.

Comment: normalizing is indeed the only clean way to go. Writing more code on top of this badly designed DB is calling for further questions ON SO about other complicated queries or performance issues...

Answer (score 0):

You can use link this:

```
   private static void commaSeperate(List<classname> obj)
    {
        string delimeter = ",";
        Console.WriteLine(obj.Aggregate((i, j) => new classname { Name = (i.Name + delimeter + j.Name) }).Name);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

This is just a sample, please modify according to your conditions.

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

This could be the solution if our retrieve the data into memory first.

```
var q = from d in Details
from m in Master
select new {Id = d.Id, CategoryName = String.Join(m.Where(i=> d.CategoryId.Split(',').Cast<int32>().Contains(i.Id).Select(i => i.Name).ToArray(), ',')}
```

Comment: i am getting the error like Invalid arguments for String.Join  @Toni

Comment: Jep, because this is only valid for in-memory queries. aka you have to retrieve your master and detail data in advance (as common lists) and operate on these lists.

Answer (score 0):

You can't join these two tables but I think below query would work for your result:

```
(from de in datacontextobj.Details
from ca in datacontextobj.Category
where de.CategoryId.Contains(ca.ID)
select de.ID, ca.Name).ToList();
```

Comment: But i need Comma separated Category Name @ShilpaSoni

Comment: Can you post what my query is returning?